# Python - Login Code not working in Kivy

Tags: python, authentication, kivy

The following error is appearing when I try to run this code. I tried in both versions of Python (2 and 3):

> **Syntax Error: Invalid syntax**

```
from Kivy.app import App
from Kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class LoginScreen(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        self.add_widget(Label(text="Username:"))
        self.username = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.username)

class SimpleKivy(App):
    def build(sef):
        return LoginScreen()
```

Comment: Could you please update the full traceback of the issue?

Comment: It should be `from kivy.app import App` and `from kivy.uix.label import Label` - lowercase names of modules.